# libpostal output string (dict) with duplicate keys and I need to convert string to Dict

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, parsing

I am using `libpostal` Address parsing library as `.exe` file. I have a script to read the output from terminal . The output will be a `string` with `dict` format like below,

[image]

This is the address string

```
"531A UPPER CROSS STREETSINGAPORE HONG LIM COMPLEX 051531 S"
```

The libpostal terminal output is

```
'{\n  "house_number": "531a",\n  "road": "upper cross streetsingapore",\n  "city": "hong",\n  "house": "lim complex",\n  "house_number": "051531 s"\n}'
```

I need to create a `Dict` from this string and if there is a duplicate key, then append the values together in the same key.

Expected output `Dict`

```
{
  "house_number": "531a 051531 s",
  "road": "upper cross streetsingapore",
  "city": "hong",
  "house": "lim complex",
}
```

helps will be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code along with your current output or errors.

Comment: I was using the `eval(dict)`, but that skips the duplicate keys. but, now i got the picture after an answer was posted here. Thank anyway @JanWilamowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json.JSONDecoder` to decode the dict literal to a list of tuples, use `dict.setdefault` to combine values to lists and finally join all items in dicts values:

```
string = '{\n  "house_number": "531a",\n  "road": "upper cross streetsingapore",\n  "city": "hong",\n  "house": "lim complex",\n  "house_number": "051531 s"\n}'

from json import JSONDecoder
decoder = JSONDecoder(object_pairs_hook=lambda x: x).decode(string)
out = {}
for tpl in decoder:
    out.setdefault(tpl[0],[]).append(tpl[1])
    
out = {k:' '.join(v) for k,v in out.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'house_number': '531a 051531 s',
 'road': 'upper cross streetsingapore',
 'city': 'hong',
 'house': 'lim complex'}
```